# Redux store for multipage react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a e-commerce website containing four different categories.
There are going to be no transactions between the categories.

I am using react and redux java script libraries to build the front-end UI components.

My question is regarding the approach for creating redux store for the website application.
Is it required to create single store for all four categories?
OR
Is it required to create one store for each category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Redux application there's always a single store which orchestrates the state of your application. But you can have separate stores implemented for different parts of you application ( in your case categories ) and then combine them to create a single root store.

For more read - https://redux.js.org/

 Also - https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers#reducersindex.js

Hope this helps!